# Setting Entry value from code behind Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set Entry text value from codebehind but I am getting "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception in cs file, where I am trying to set value "Scott".

This is my XAML file:

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Margin="40">
        <Label Text="Enter your display name:"/>
        <Entry x:Name="displayNameEntry" />
        <Button Text="Save" />
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is my cs file

```
public SettingsPage ()
        {
            InitializeSettings();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeSettings()
        {
            displayNameEntry.Text = "Scott";            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InitializeComponent()` need to be execute first so the XAML is inflated and thus the components/objects have be assigned:

```
public SettingsPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // First
    InitializeSettings(); // Second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `InitializeComponent` prior to the call of `InitializeSettings`, in order the corresponding objects to be created first and then modify their attributes.